# How to add additional column headers to excel from list using openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I would like to add additional column headers for my dataframe using a list and openpyxl.  See code snippets below.

```py
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as pyxl
from openpyxl.styles import font
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
.
.
.
workbook = Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active

myList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'KK', 'ee']
```

mySQL1_details is a dataframe with 5 columns

how can I write the first header using myList and worksheet.append?
I know how to write out dataframe with headers

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find answer:
worksheet.append(myList)